# Subsetting in R vs filter(from dplyr) giving different results

Tags: r, dplyr

I am wondering if you can please share your insights on the following issue I am having in R.
I am working on an assignment which involves the following dataset:
https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Individual+household+electric+power+consumption#

The question asks to only consider data for specific dates in this dataset, and the first ask is to plot a histogram. Previously, I had used the following code in R, and the results I got had 3121 observations.

...data manipulation steps, followed by:

```r
data2 <- data1[(data1$DateTime >= "2007-02-01 00:00:00" & data1$DateTime <= "2007-02-03 00:00:00"), ]
```

After learning about dplyr, I came back to the same question to make sure I'd be getting the same results using dplyr. However, when I filter, I get 2881 observations.

...data manipulation steps, followed by:

```r
house3 <- filter(house2, datetime >= "2007-02-01 00:00:00" & datetime <= "2007-02-03 00:00:00")
```

I went back and viewed the subsetting from earlier (using []) and found that the remaining rows (3121 - 2881) had a bunch of NAs. However, when I move forward with this data, I get the correct histogram (we are supposed to write code that gives a specific histogram), while the one using filter from dplyr gives a similar but incorrect histogram.

I am trying to figure out what I am doing wrong. I am wondering if you guys have any insights, and/or thoughts on the differences in the results. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there are `NA`s make sure to adjust for the `NA` elements with `is.na` or else `filter` by default will remove those rows

```
library(dplyr)
filter(house2, (datetime >= "2007-02-01 00:00:00" & 
                datetime <= "2007-02-03 00:00:00")|
                is.na(datetime))
```

According to `?filter`

> The filter() function is used to subset a data frame, retaining all rows that satisfy your conditions. To be retained, the row must produce a value of TRUE for all conditions. Note that when a condition evaluates to NA the row will be dropped, unlike base subsetting with [.

Comment: Thanks so much Akrun, this helps. Using the above code I am now getting the same number of observations.