# Calculating mean by logical subsetting vs piping in dplyr appears to return different results

Tags: r, dplyr, filter, pipe

I've been trying to improve the speed of my code by implementing filter and join operations. However on close inspection I've noticed the two different approaches seem to return slightly different results for the same function (in my case calculating the mean of a vector)

I am looking at time series data and want to calculate the baseline (i.e. mean) of some response value (Mean_Intensity) at a specific time frame. My simplified data looks as such

```
time Neuron_ID                             Mean_Intensity DrugApp1
  <dbl> <fct>                                          <dbl> <dbl>
1     0 GLP_1_200nM_16_02_2023_p2_f1_Neuron_1           9.88   300
2     0 GLP_1_200nM_16_02_2023_p2_f1_Neuron_2          11.8    300
3     0 GLP_1_200nM_16_02_2023_p2_f1_Neuron_3           8.45   300
4     0 GLP_1_200nM_16_02_2023_p2_f1_Neuron_4           9.99   300
5     0 GLP_1_200nM_16_02_2023_p2_f1_Neuron_5           4.48   300
6     0 GLP_1_20nM_23_02_2023_p3_f1_Neuron_1            9.89   300
```

The Old Approach was as follows

```
df_baseline <- df %>%
  filter(time >= (DrugApp1 - 260), time <= (DrugApp1 + 750)) %>%
  group_by(Neuron_ID) %>%
  mutate(F0 = mean(Mean_Intensity[time <= DrugApp1], na.rm = TRUE))
```

My New Code implementing filter

```
df_baseline_new <- df %>%
  filter(time >= (DrugApp1 - 260), time <= DrugApp1) %>%
  group_by(Neuron_ID) %>%
  mutate(F0 = mean(Mean_Intensity, na.rm = TRUE))
```

However for the same variable these two methods seem to return slightly different values for F0

E.g. For a given Neuron_ID the two methods seem to return a value of F0 of 2.906231, or 2.911889 respectively.

The slight difference makes me think this is being caused by `mutate(F0 = mean(Mean_Intensity[time <= DrugApp1], na.rm = TRUE))` having a different length of `time` than `filter(time >= (DrugApp1 - 260), time <= (DrugApp1 + 750))`. I thought it may be to do with including/excluding an extra time point with the <=/< operators but I tried many combinations of these and couldn't get them to be the same and I'm not sure how I could check what range of time `mutate(F0 = mean(Mean_Intensity[time <= DrugApp1], na.rm = TRUE))` is acting on.

[I'm aware that filter removes NA values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66018463/subsetting-in-r-vs-filterfrom-dplyr-giving-different-results) however I have tidied my data and `df_baseline_new` has not dropped any values which could explain this.

As it stands I think the new code is more likely to be correct; I can see in `df_baseline_new` the filtered `time` points are as I would expect - so it's not too much of an issue as it is substantially faster (2.01s vs 340s), however I would like to know what's causing this to happen. Any help would be appreciated.

**EDIT**

Some sample code which recreates the problem:

```
structure(list(time = c(0, 0, 0, 10, 10, 10, 20, 20, 20, 30, 
30, 30, 40, 40, 40, 50, 50, 50, 60, 60, 60, 70, 70, 70, 80, 80, 
80, 90, 90, 90, 100, 100, 100, 110, 110, 110, 120, 120, 120, 
130, 130, 130, 140, 140, 140, 150, 150, 150, 160, 160, 160, 170, 
170, 170, 180, 180, 180, 190, 190, 190, 200, 200, 200, 210, 210, 
210, 220, 220, 220, 230, 230, 230, 240, 240, 240, 250, 250, 250, 
260, 260, 260, 270, 270, 270, 280, 280, 280, 290, 290, 290, 300, 
300, 300, 310, 310, 310, 320, 320, 320, 330, 330, 330, 340, 340, 
340, 350, 350, 350, 360, 360, 360, 370, 370, 370, 380, 380, 380, 
390, 390, 390, 400, 400, 400, 410, 410, 410, 420, 420, 420, 430, 
430, 430, 440, 440, 440, 450, 450, 450, 460, 460, 460, 470, 470, 
470, 480, 480, 480, 490, 490, 490, 500, 500, 500, 510, 510, 510, 
520, 520, 520, 530, 530, 530, 540, 540, 540, 550, 550, 550, 560, 
560, 560, 570, 570, 570, 580, 580, 580, 590, 590, 590, 600, 600, 
600, 610, 610, 610, 620, 620, 620, 630, 630, 630, 640, 640, 640, 
650, 650, 650, 660, 660, 660, 670, 670, 670, 680, 680, 680, 690, 
690, 690, 700, 700, 700, 710, 710, 710, 720, 720, 720, 730, 730, 
730, 740, 740, 740, 750, 750, 750, 760, 760, 760, 770, 770, 770, 
780, 780, 780, 790, 790, 790, 800, 800, 800, 810, 810, 810, 820, 
820, 820, 830, 830, 830, 840, 840, 840, 850, 850, 850, 860, 860, 
860, 870, 870, 870, 880, 880, 880, 890, 890, 890, 900, 900, 900, 
910, 910, 910, 920, 920, 920, 930, 930, 930, 940, 940, 940, 950, 
950, 950, 960, 960, 960, 970, 970, 970, 980, 980, 980, 990, 990, 
990, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1010, 1010, 1010), Neuron_ID = structure(c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 
3L), levels = c("POMC_GFP_GLP_1_50nM_23_02_23_p1_f1_Neuron_3", 
"POMC_GFP_GLP_1_50nM_23_02_23_p1_f1_Neuron_4", "POMC_GFP_GLP_1_50nM_23_02_23_p1_f1_Neuron_5"
), class = "factor"), Mean_Intensity = c(17.592, 10.148, 2.753, 
16.496, 9.785, 2.684, 18.887, 9.681, 2.78700000000001, 19.068, 
10.181, 2.71300000000001, 19.463, 10.072, 2.86999999999999, 18.075, 
9.795, 2.70699999999999, 17.515, 9.7, 2.74300000000001, 17.35, 
9.55800000000001, 2.61200000000001, 18.055, 9.35899999999999, 
2.67999999999999, 18.119, 9.11799999999999, 2.68599999999999, 
18.136, 9.298, 2.715, 18.648, 9.54899999999999, 2.744, 18.41, 
9.45399999999999, 2.866, 16.803, 9.75700000000001, 2.941, 18.081, 
9.76000000000001, 2.64, 17.018, 9.574, 3.283, 19.086, 10.122, 
2.98299999999999, 18.874, 9.97699999999999, 2.94799999999999, 
18.416, 9.556, 3.178, 19.367, 9.62, 2.852, 19.236, 9.68599999999999, 
2.875, 19.282, 9.76000000000001, 3.479, 20.024, 9.64100000000001, 
3.15600000000001, 20.177, 9.85499999999999, 3.077, 20.53, 9.29900000000001, 
3.096, 19.449, 9.595, 3.352, 17.926, 9.52499999999999, 3.20099999999999, 
18.146, 9.398, 3.101, 17.706, 9.355, 2.952, 18.222, 9.41800000000001, 
3, 19.932, 9.46600000000001, 2.941, 20.391, 9.47500000000001, 
2.943, 19.975, 9.449, 2.86199999999999, 19.704, 9.63, 3.029, 
20.318, 9.247, 2.711, 21.773, 9.613, 2.756, 21.757, 9.753, 2.78, 
21.396, 9.396, 2.75, 21.837, 9.721, 2.89700000000001, 20.221, 
9.387, 2.718, 20.905, 9.26400000000001, 2.80900000000001, 19.763, 
9.50399999999999, 2.759, 20.885, 9.821, 2.949, 21.624, 9.411, 
2.65400000000001, 21.694, 9.316, 3.167, 21.947, 9.56100000000001, 
3.52000000000001, 23.746, 9.245, 3.14500000000001, 24.241, 9.366, 
3.23099999999999, 23.875, 9.491, 3.28, 24.328, 9.361, 3.03700000000001, 
23.937, 8.99600000000001, 2.78100000000001, 23.383, 9.083, 2.94200000000001, 
23.297, 9.295, 3.29900000000001, 23.183, 9.20100000000001, 3.21300000000001, 
22.493, 9.111, 3.24300000000001, 23.056, 9.09400000000001, 2.967, 
23.406, 9.16199999999999, 3.226, 25.179, 9.277, 3.295, 25.679, 
9.024, 3.134, 25.215, 8.986, 3.19199999999999, 24.382, 9.048, 
3.28, 25.559, 9.33, 3.352, 25.122, 9.575, 3.27200000000001, 25.637, 
9.303, 3.33, 23.172, 9.176, 3.31, 24.396, 9.349, 3.32300000000001, 
23.88, 9.313, 3.321, 23.421, 9.304, 3.19, 24.431, 9.16399999999999, 
3.22999999999999, 25.018, 9.01900000000001, 3.363, 25.232, 9.128, 
3.53999999999999, 25.348, 9.206, 3.43900000000001, 25.399, 9.497, 
3.298, 24.746, 9.069, 2.967, 25.702, 9.107, 3.26299999999999, 
25.793, 9.36500000000001, 3.292, 25.703, 9.111, 3.148, 25.637, 
9.38800000000001, 3.328, 25.759, 9.384, 3.42399999999999, 23.973, 
9.53200000000001, 3.39400000000001, 23.623, 9.649, 3.497, 25.759, 
9.78500000000001, 3.65700000000001, 25.619, 9.64400000000001, 
3.28, 24.842, 9.813, 3.48400000000001, 24.342, 9.759, 3.55, 23.872, 
9.711, 3.474, 21.907, 9.794, 3.26299999999999, 21.298, 9.56, 
2.869, 21.291, 9.752, 3.227, 21.236, 9.76799999999999, 3.15299999999999, 
21.887, 9.93000000000001, 3.169, 22.742, 9.848, 3.22, 22.095, 
10.115, 3.622, 22.043, 10.031, 3.73, 21.19, 10.041, 3.548, 21.572, 
9.992, 3.476, 23.337, 10.255, 3.67099999999999, 23.556, 10.142, 
3.459, 22.683, 10.26, 3.56, 23.389, 10.289, 3.42999999999999, 
23.686, 10.025, 3.15900000000001, 23.687, 10.147, 3.12700000000001
), DrugApp1 = c(300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 
300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 
300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 
300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 
300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 
300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 
300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 
300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 
300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 
300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 
300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 
300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 
300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 
300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 
300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 
300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 
300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 
300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 
300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 
300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 
300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 
300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 
300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 
300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300)), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -306L), groups = structure(list(
    Neuron_ID = structure(1:3, levels = c("POMC_GFP_GLP_1_50nM_23_02_23_p1_f1_Neuron_3", 
    "POMC_GFP_GLP_1_50nM_23_02_23_p1_f1_Neuron_4", "POMC_GFP_GLP_1_50nM_23_02_23_p1_f1_Neuron_5"
    ), class = "factor"), .rows = structure(list(c(1L, 4L, 7L, 
    10L, 13L, 16L, 19L, 22L, 25L, 28L, 31L, 34L, 37L, 40L, 43L, 
    46L, 49L, 52L, 55L, 58L, 61L, 64L, 67L, 70L, 73L, 76L, 79L, 
    82L, 85L, 88L, 91L, 94L, 97L, 100L, 103L, 106L, 109L, 112L, 
    115L, 118L, 121L, 124L, 127L, 130L, 133L, 136L, 139L, 142L, 
    145L, 148L, 151L, 154L, 157L, 160L, 163L, 166L, 169L, 172L, 
    175L, 178L, 181L, 184L, 187L, 190L, 193L, 196L, 199L, 202L, 
    205L, 208L, 211L, 214L, 217L, 220L, 223L, 226L, 229L, 232L, 
    235L, 238L, 241L, 244L, 247L, 250L, 253L, 256L, 259L, 262L, 
    265L, 268L, 271L, 274L, 277L, 280L, 283L, 286L, 289L, 292L, 
    295L, 298L, 301L, 304L), c(2L, 5L, 8L, 11L, 14L, 17L, 20L, 
    23L, 26L, 29L, 32L, 35L, 38L, 41L, 44L, 47L, 50L, 53L, 56L, 
    59L, 62L, 65L, 68L, 71L, 74L, 77L, 80L, 83L, 86L, 89L, 92L, 
    95L, 98L, 101L, 104L, 107L, 110L, 113L, 116L, 119L, 122L, 
    125L, 128L, 131L, 134L, 137L, 140L, 143L, 146L, 149L, 152L, 
    155L, 158L, 161L, 164L, 167L, 170L, 173L, 176L, 179L, 182L, 
    185L, 188L, 191L, 194L, 197L, 200L, 203L, 206L, 209L, 212L, 
    215L, 218L, 221L, 224L, 227L, 230L, 233L, 236L, 239L, 242L, 
    245L, 248L, 251L, 254L, 257L, 260L, 263L, 266L, 269L, 272L, 
    275L, 278L, 281L, 284L, 287L, 290L, 293L, 296L, 299L, 302L, 
    305L), c(3L, 6L, 9L, 12L, 15L, 18L, 21L, 24L, 27L, 30L, 33L, 
    36L, 39L, 42L, 45L, 48L, 51L, 54L, 57L, 60L, 63L, 66L, 69L, 
    72L, 75L, 78L, 81L, 84L, 87L, 90L, 93L, 96L, 99L, 102L, 105L, 
    108L, 111L, 114L, 117L, 120L, 123L, 126L, 129L, 132L, 135L, 
    138L, 141L, 144L, 147L, 150L, 153L, 156L, 159L, 162L, 165L, 
    168L, 171L, 174L, 177L, 180L, 183L, 186L, 189L, 192L, 195L, 
    198L, 201L, 204L, 207L, 210L, 213L, 216L, 219L, 222L, 225L, 
    228L, 231L, 234L, 237L, 240L, 243L, 246L, 249L, 252L, 255L, 
    258L, 261L, 264L, 267L, 270L, 273L, 276L, 279L, 282L, 285L, 
    288L, 291L, 294L, 297L, 300L, 303L, 306L)), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -3L), .drop = TRUE))
```

Ok so my issue was due to the fact `DrugApp1` was actually a numerical vector of the same size as my data frame. As this is a script that I am running on many different datasets with different variable names (which I extract as `DrugApp1String`), I have an early piece of code which converts the different variable names into a common one `DrugApp1`. I intended to do this:

```
df$DrugApp1 <- df[,c(DrugApp1_string)]
```

however what happened was

```
DrugApp1 <- df[,c(DrugApp1_string)]
```

which was causing the misalignment to occur, and I think also caused my code to run slowly. Very very annoying.

Thank you very much for the help!

Comment: It'll be easier to hep if you can share some example data that demonstrates the different F0 values. Can you find some example data that gives differing values, convert that data subset to code using `dput()` and then paste into your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're running the code on different data sets, `df` in the first block, `data_FINAL` in the second block. If you want to check the differences, run both sets of code on the same data, modifying the column names so you can tell which is which, and add some flags to mark which rows are included in each mean. Something like this:

```
data_FINAL$id = 1:nrow(data_FINAL) # add ID variable so we can compare

result_new = data_FINAL %>%
  filter(time >= (DrugApp1 - 260), time <= DrugApp1) %>%
  group_by(Neuron_ID) %>%
  mutate(
    included_new = TRUE,
    F0_new = mean(Mean_Intensity, na.rm = TRUE)
  ) 

result_old <- data_FINAL %>% ## use the same data
  filter(time >= (DrugApp1 - 260), time <= (DrugApp1 + 750)) %>%
  group_by(Neuron_ID) %>%
  mutate(
    included_old = time <= DrugApp1,
    F0 = mean(Mean_Intensity[time <= DrugApp1], na.rm = TRUE)
  )
```

Then you can join and compare

```
result_old |> 
  full_join(result_new, by = "ID", suffix = c("_old", "_new")) |>
  filter(included_old != included_new)
```

This should give you a result of any rows included in one mean but not the other.

Comment: Sorry that was a typo, both bits of code are being run on the same dataset, however your code helped me figure out what was going wrong. Thank you very much!